# Python Format %s subdirectories and write

Tags: python, file

I have multiple subfolders where each subfolder have 2 images inside of them.

My goal is take each image(file) and replace with `%s` and write to `latex.txt` in same folder. And do this for each folder.

So far I can create `.txt` file in each folder and write on it.

However, I can not replace `%s` with image names also, my `.txt` file is not writing in new line where it has `\n`

```
import os

walk_dir = 'C:/Users/xx/Desktop/main/'

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(walk_dir):
    list_file_path = os.path.join(root, 'latex.txt')

    with open(list_file_path, 'wb') as list_file:
        all_image = []
        for filename in files:
            all_files = []
            all_image.append(filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        #print(all_image)
        list_file.write(("\\documentclass{article} \n" \
             "\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \n" \
             "\\usepackage{graphicx} \n" \
             "\n" \
             "\\usepackage{subcaption} \n " \
             "\n" \
             "\\hspace*{-3cm} \n" \
             "\\begin{subfigure}{0.6\\textwidth} \n" \
             "\centering \n" \
             "\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{%s} \n" \
             "\label{fig:sfig1} \n" \
             "\end{subfigure}%% \n" \
             "\hspace{0.5in} \n" \
             "\\begin{subfigure}{0.6\\textwidth} \n" \
             "\centering \n" \
             "\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{%s} \n" \
             "\label{fig:sfig2} \n" \
             "\end{subfigure} \n" \

             "\label{fig:fig} \n" \
             "\end{figure} \n" \
             "\end{document}" % filename, filename).encode('utf-8'))
```

when I `print(images)` I get images in list for each subfolder.

`"\end{document}" % filename).encode('utf-8'))` I change this code here multiple times, try to get values from list put nothing worked. I left here what I start with. This only replaces last image with `%s`

Comment: You have `%s` twice which should raise a `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: You also should be using `os.linesep` instead of `\n` for your newlines.

Comment: @bernie you're right, I had to remove one `%s` order to work properly but still I dont get my desire output

Comment: Ok so where do you want the filename to be inserted?

Comment: use triple quotes like ''' or """

Comment: @bernie where there is two `%s`

Comment: Ctrl+F  ........ %s

Comment: @YOU will that write in line? I will give that try now

Comment: I am commenting on minor nits, not about actual issue.

Comment: @YOU I understand, thank you

Comment: I guess you just need replace `% filename` with `% (filename, filename)`

Comment: `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: What @YOU suggested should work with the code you've posted. Can you please edit your question with your current code?

Comment: @bernie I did edit with exactly what I have, and I get `TypeError` I just want to say again there is multiple subfolders and each subfolders have 2 images

Comment: Oh you need `% (filename, filename)` instead of `% filename, filename`

Comment: `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` bernie I really appreciated for trying to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, you also had a misplaced `\end{tabular}` in your LaTeX code that I removed. Also collects the file paths to images in the `images` variable as you asked.

```
import os
walk_dir = 'C:/Users/XX/Desktop/Main/'

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(walk_dir):
    list_file_path = os.path.join(root, 'latex.txt')

    with open(list_file_path, 'w') as list_file:
        images = []
        for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            images.append(file_path)

        if len(images) >= 1:
            document = """
            \\documentclass{article}
            \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
            \\usepackage{graphicx}
            \\usepackage{subcaption}
            \\hfill  & \\Large \\textbf{EXAMPLE}
            \\hspace*{-3cm}
            %s
            \\end{document}
            """
            figure = """
            \\begin{subfigure}{0.6\\textwidth}
            \\centering
            \\includegraphics[width=1\\linewidth]{%s}
            \\label{fig:sfig%d}
            \\end{subfigure}
            """
            separator = """
            \\hspace{0.5in}
            """
            figures = separator.join([figure % (image, i) for i, image in enumerate(images)])
            list_file.write(document % figures)
```

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range`  We are loop over subfolders to get multiple files `for filename in files:`

Comment: Right, edited the answer, try now. The error you get happens when a subdir you walk doesn't have 2 files in it. Depending on your directory structure you may not even need to do `os.walk`.

Comment: This worked perfectly!!! Thank you!! I am guessing this will work just if I have more than 2 images? Just have to add to here `% (images[0], images[1])))`

Comment: Not really, but I edited and it now should work for any amount of images in a directory. You should also maybe add a `if filename.endsWith(".png")` into your loop over `files` or whatever image format you are using, so that it only picks up images and not other files.

Comment: Thank you!! I have another script that creates this subfolders for me with appropriate png files in them using `startswith` and `endswith`